# Как изменить элементы массива по условию?

Tags: javascript

Имеется примерно такой массив:

```
let arr = [1000, 2005, 600, 4000, 5000];
```

Задача состоит в том, что нужно изменить определенные значения в массиве по условию, то есть, например если какой-либо элемент массива равен `1000`, тогда заменяем его значение на `"1К +"` и так далее.

Казалось бы задача простая, но попытка решить её подобным образом:

```js
let arr = [1000, 2005, 600, 4000, 5000];
let newArray = [];

arr.forEach(n => {
          switch (true) {
               case n > 999:
                    n = "1К +";
               case n > 2000:
                    n = "2К +";
               case n > 4000:
                    n = "4К +";
               case n > 5000:
                    n = "5К +";
          }

       newArray.push(n);
     });

console.log(newArray);
```

Приводит к такому результату:

```
["5К +", "5К +", 600, "5К +", "5К +"]
```

То есть, первое и второе условие игнорируется, и выполняется последнее. Получается что элементы массива, значения которых выше 999, получают обновленные значения, равные = `5000(5К+)`, но это неправильно, так как например `1000` должен быть обновлен следующим значением = `1К +`.

Нужный результат должен выглядеть вот так:

```
["1К +", "2К +", 600, "4К +", "5К +"]
```

Попытка добавлять break в case, не даёт никаких положительных результатов. Условий может быть много, поэтому был выбрал `switch` вместо `if else` для сохранения читаемости кода. Но даже если пожертвовать читаемостью кода и попытаться переписать на `if else if else`, или `if(), if(), if()` то всё равно никакого нужного результата не будет.

Есть какой-нибудь способ это решить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let arr = [1000, 2005, 600, 4000, 5000];
let newArray = arr.map((el) => {
  const result = Math.floor(el / 1000);
  return result < 1 ? el : `${result}K +`;
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: огромное спасибо! Работает ровно так, как и нужно.